# How to POST multipart/form-data using Vegeta?

Tags: http, request, multipartform-data, vegeta

I wanted to request POST a image file as multipart/form-data with Vegeta

But when I use this code, it didn't work well. As I thought, 'mean of Bytes In' in Vegeta report needed to be over 20000 because of the image size, but it was just 55.00

I command like this because it is on Windows Power Shell

```
PS >vegeta attack -duration=10s -rate 100 -targets .\targets_formdata.txt -output output\results.bin
```

**targets_formdata.txt**

```
POST http://url/to/request
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+1234
@body.txt
```

**body.txt**

```
--Boundary+1234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="DvBp50cVYAEIfxd.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

I wrote `--Boundary+1234` as really it is, as `--Boundary+1234`, this could be a problem? I don't know what is the real problem.